# Want to create search products filter by width or filter by height same like filter by price in wordpress WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, jquery-plugins

In WooCommerce I would like to create search products filter by width or filter by height same like filter by price in wordpress WooCommerce

You can see the products with their title below:[image]

Website link: https://asiatic.endroid1.com/shop

Answer (score 0):

Create width and height attribute in admin then put the value of attribute in product.
Then in your sidebar can add multiple filter in woocommerce  for each attribute.
after setting you will see new filter in sidebar for height and width as price filter

Comment: i Create width and height attribute in admin then put the value of attribute in product. but  in sidebar range filter  same like price filter option not available or show for each attribute.

Comment: Go to widget and check which sidebar added price filter, you have to add one more filter here and then you can see both height and width attribute in it. so you just need to select and save it. it will add one more filter in front side

Comment: In widget showing only three options....1.Inline, 2. Dropdown, 3.checkbox......not showing option range slider

Comment: Right now there is no option for ranger slider attribute, There has some paid plugin   which may fulfill your requirement either you can create custom field of product and through jquery ajax you can  create range slider.

Comment: Can you refer me some plugin

Comment: or any custom code for jquery ajax  range slider for WordPress

Comment: You can see demo of this plugin, i naver used it but can check all your requirement https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/